# Lambda Include restrict Columns

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a object "Property" that has children "Notes" and "Attachments".
I want to bring back back the entire "Property", all the associated "Notes" BUT just one field from "Attachment". I dont want to bring back the entire "Attachments" as this contains base64 images which are huge. If I need these I can get them through the "AttachmentId". the question is how does one narrow down the fields when using Lambda Include. The following doesnt work. I really dont want to create a long winded LINQ Statement

```
var property = await _context.Property
                .Include(x => x.Notes)
                .Include(x => x.Attachments.Select(y => new PropertyAttachment
                {
                    PropertyId = y.PropertyId,
                    AttachmentId = y.AttachmentId,
                    Type = y.Type,
                    Title = y.Title,
                    Content = ""
                }).ToList())
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.PropertyId == key);
```

Comment: So you need to use Linq `Select` to project your data into a new format. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations#selecting-projections)

Comment: I tried that as you can see in the source code....but causes syntax issues.

Comment: But you haven't told us what those syntax issues are, we can't guess I'm afraid.

Comment: Changed the code but get error: The property expression 'x => {from PropertyAttachment y in x.Attachments select new PropertyAttachment() {PropertyId = [y].PropertyId, AttachmentId = [y].AttachmentId, Type = [y].Type, Title = [y].Title, Content = ""}}.ToList()' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

Answer (score 1):

Using select and anonymous type you can try like so

```
var property = _context.Property.Select(x => new 
   { Property = x,
     HMOUnits = x.HMOUnits,
     Notes = x.Notes,
     AttachmendId = new { Id = x.Attachments.Select(z=> z.AttachmentId) }
   })
   .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x =>
        x.Property.ID == key &&
       (RestrictUser(User) ? x.Property.Tenancies.Any(y => y.Assignments.Any(z => z.Tenant.UserID == Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name))) : true) 
   );
```

Comment: I tried that but that causes more issues downstream (Angular 4) as the "property" is treated as an object with child collections. This solu. would create an object with Property as an Object. Of course I could just list out all the fields and still use the collections as specified.

Comment: You have to create a new object type because the type of Property object hasn't property AttachmendId. I have created here an anonymous  type

Comment: even as anoymous type...it produces same error  var property = await _context.Property
                    .Include(x => x.Notes)
                    .Include(x => x.Attachments.Select(y => new 
                    {
                        PropertyId = y.PropertyId,
                        AttachmentId = y.AttachmentId,
                        Type = y.Type,
                        Title = y.Title,
                        Content = ""
                    }))
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.PropertyId == key);

Comment: In the include function we can use existing navigation property from the parent object. We cann't use any select.